# How to show categories and date on posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to categorise posts and show them on my WordPress website. So in order to achieve that I've written a code. My code is below.

```
function wpb_postsbycategory() {
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'category_name' => 'travel', 
    'posts_per_page' => 5 
) ); 
   
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $string .= '<ul class="postsbycategory widget_recent_entries">';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $string .= '<li>';
            $string .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 50, 50) ) . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
            } else { 
            // if no featured image is found
            $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
            }
            }
    } else {
    // no posts found
 $string .= '<li>No Posts Found</li>';
}
$string .= '</ul>';
   
return $string;
   
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
}
// Add a shortcode
add_shortcode('categoryposts', 'wpb_postsbycategory');
```

This code works perfectly fine. However, I want to show posts meta descriptions as well (i.e post created date and the category). How would I achieve that? Right now It only extracts the post heading and the image. Thanks so much for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function wpb_postsbycategory() {
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'category_name' => 'travel', 
    'posts_per_page' => 5 
) ); 
   
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $string .= '<ul class="postsbycategory widget_recent_entries">';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
            $string .= '<li>';
            $string .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">';
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                $string .= get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 50, 50) );
            }
            // title
            $string .= get_the_title();
            // date
            $string .= get_the_date();
            // categories
            $categories = get_the_category();
            $category_list = join( ', ', wp_list_pluck( $categories, 'name' ) );
            $string .= wp_kses_post( $category_list );
            // close link
            $string .= '</a></li>';
    }
    // no posts found
 $string .= '<li>No Posts Found</li>';
}
$string .= '</ul>';
   
return $string;
   
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
}
// Add a shortcode
add_shortcode('categoryposts', 'wpb_postsbycategory');
```

I guess you need/want to add HTML tags around date and category.

For example:

```
$string .= '<span class="date">'.get_the_date().'</span>';
```

But that's up to you.

You can change the output of the categories based on the docs [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/).

Comment: Hi @Cray Thanks for the support :) It shows the date but does not showing the category :( what could be wrong?

Comment: I've changed my code. Now it shows the categories of the post

Comment: Wow thanks so much It's working.